# Parametric Scoring Function or Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

I'm trying to come up with a way to arrive at a "score" based on an integer number of "points" that is adjustable using a small number (3-5?) of parameters. Preferably it would be simple enough to reasonably enter as a function/calculation in a spreadsheet for tuning the parameters by the "designer" (not a programmer or mathematician). The first point has the most value and eventually additional points have a fixed or nearly fixed value. The transition from the initial slope of point value to final slope would be *smooth*. See example shapes below.

- Points values are always positive integers (0 pts = 0 score)
- At some point, curve is linear (or nearly), all additional points have fixed value
- Preferably, parameters are understandable to a lay person, e.g.: "smoothness of the curve", "value of first point", "place where the additional value of points is fixed", etc

For parameters, an example of something ideal would be:

- Value of first point: `10`
- Value of point #: `3` is: `5`
- Minimum value of additional points: `0.75`

Exact shape of curve not too important as long as the corner can be more *smooth* or more *sharp*.

This is not for a game but more of a rating system with multiple components (several of which might use this kind of *scale*) will be combined.

This seems like a non-traditional kind of question for SO/SE. I've done mostly financial software in my career, I'm hoping there some domain wisdom for this kind of thing I can tap into.

[image]

#### Implementation of Prune's Solution:

[image]

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e5aYmNYHGaP966ek7OJoKlKV1rvu4Ygwfs_ATsyi1Uc)

Comment: What do you want from us?  You have several good examples of solutions here.  Do you need a general formula given the quantity of points?  What other properties would be desirable?  As you've given the problem, all you need is a simple function with a starting point and decay property, with a positive horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Yes, as you put succinctly: a simple function with a starting point and decay property, with a positive horizontal asymptote, that's what I want. The examples are ginned up data that I can't really provide adjustment knob-like parameters. A more complex function but with parameters that are more relatable as described above would be ideal. I can't really come up with those functions given my limited and decades old (mostly forgotten) math background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters:

- Initial value (a)
- Second value (b)
- Minimum value (z)

Your decay ratio is b/a.  It's simple from here: iterate through your values, applying the decay at each step, until you "peg" at the minimum:

```
x[n] = max( z, a * (b/a)^n )
// Take the larger of the computed "decayed" value, 
//   and the specified minimum.
```

The sequence **x** is your values list.

You can also truncate intermediate results if you want integers up to a certain point.  Just apply the **floor** function to each computed value, but still allow **z** to override that if it gets too small.

Is that good enough?  I know there's a discontinuity in the derivative function, which will be noticeable if the minimum and decay aren't pleasantly aligned.  You can adjust this with a relative decay, translating the exponential decay curve from y = 0 to **z**.

```
base = z
diff = a-z
ratio = (b-z) / diff

x[n] = z + diff * ratio^n
```

In this case, you don't need the **max** function, since the decay has a natural asymptote of 0.